# Adding values to same key as list in HashMap Table in Lisp

Tags: hashmap, lisp

I want to write a function that will take key and value as parameter. Such that If key already exist in table then it will add value to its current value in list.

For example,

```
(setf (gethash "key" table) 1) ==> 1 as Value of Key
(setf (gethash "key" table) 2) ==> (1 2) as Value of key
```

I have function checker that performs that

```
(defun checker(_key values) 
  (if (gethash _key table)
    (let 
      (setf lists (gethash _key table))
      (push values lists)
      (setf (gethash _key table) lists))
    (setf (gethash _key table) values)))
```

I get following error:

> Bad Binding (gethash _key table)

Comment: A hash-table cannot contains two entries for one key, except of course if you map keys to sequences. Your question is unclear and won't be reopened until you give a better description of your problem, with actual code that show precisely what you have and what you need.

Comment: Ohk sorry for being very vague. I have edited question. Please let me know if i need more information

Comment: This is way better, I voted to reopen.

Comment: [LET](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm) is done as follows: `(let <bindings> <body>)`, where binding is a list of either `<var>` or `(<var> <value>)` elements. Here you are defining a variable named `setf`, another one named `lists`, but the third one is not a proper binding. There is a shorter way to do what you want thanks to [places](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_ab.htm):  `(push e (gethash K table nil))`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That has solved the question. But I am just curious,  is there any way we can add element to in sorted order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LET`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm) has the following syntax:

```
(let <bindings> <body>)
```

... where binding is a list of either `<var>` or `(<var> <value>)` elements. Here you are defining a variable named `setf`, another one named `lists`, but the third one is not a proper binding.

The fixed version of your code would be:

```
(defun checker (key value)
  (let ((list (gethash key table)))
    (cond
      (list 
       (push value list)
       (setf (gethash key table) list))
      (t (setf (gethash key table) (list value))))))
```

However, you might notice that there is a lot of redundant code. All you need is:

```
(defun table-push (key table value)
  (push value (gethash key table)))
```

[`PUSH`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_push.htm) operates on a place, and [`GETHASH`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gethas.htm) can be used to modify an entry.

If you need to sort the list, you can use [`MERGE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_merge.htm) and do this:

```
(defun push-sorted-table (key table value &key (predicate #'<))
  (setf (gethash key table)
        (merge 'list
               (list value)
               (gethash key table)
               predicate)))
```

This will destructively modify existing lists, but you probably don't mind as long as you only access the list through the table and do not keep pointers to inner cons cells from other parts of your code.
For large datasets, you could store a balanced tree instead of a list so that insertion of new elements is asymptotically better.